# Calculate the code instruction in the Text Segment in MIPS

Tags: mips32, mars-simulator

How can I calculate the code of instruction in the Text Segment in MIPS ?

I am talking about this section (if its not clear):

[Code in the Text Segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rclRh.jpg)

A. Lets say I have code instruction 0x9109FF9C how do I translate it to a readable instruction in MIPS ?

B. And the other way around if I have the instruction :

```
.text 0x400000
  beq $1,$2,label
 addi $a1,$a1,1
.text 0x410004
label: add $s1,$s2,$s3
```

How do I code the beq so It will contain and jump correctly to label (if they are equal of course)